# Symplectic linear multistep method?

Tags: ode, simulation, differential-equations

I'm doing a gravitational n-body simulator and I'm thinking of implementing linear multistep methods like Adam-Bashforth. But is there any symplectic multistep methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but you have to mean symplectic on a higher-dimensional phase space than your original problem that includes previous steps too. As I understand there are also some subtle stability issues too. Rather than try to summarize, I'll just refer you to chapter 15, section 4 of Hairer, Lubich, Wanner, [Geometric Numerical Integration](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540306634). That book is a must-have if you're working on these sorts of problems, albeit a little dense.

I also think it's telling that symplectic Runge-Kutta methods are always discussed front-and-center, whereas symplectic multi-step methods are barely mentioned in [this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=iUjvAAAAMAAJ) and not mentioned at all in [this one](https://books.google.com/books?id=tpb-tnsZi5YC). If you wanted the most payoff for the least effort you might have a better time implementing higher-order symplectic Runge Kutta methods instead.

Comment: "If you wanted the most payoff for the least effort you might have a better time implementing higher-order symplectic Runge Kutta methods instead.". Indeed, there are a few results that are discussed in the books about multistep methods, and generally it just shows that the possibilities are limiting. This is definitely a case where RK is more natural.